# How to sort vector into bins in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector that consists of numbers that can take on any value between 1 and 100.
I want to sort that vector into bins of a certain size.

My logic:

1.) Divide the range (in this case, 1:100) into the amount of bins you want (lets say 10 for this example)

Result: (1, 10.9], 10.9,20.8],  (20.8,30.7],  (30.7,40.6],  (40.6,50.5],  (50.5,60.4],  (60.4,70.3],  (70.3,80.2],  (80.2,90.1],   (90.1,100]

2.) Then sort my vector

---

I found a handy function that *almost* does all this in one fell swoop: `cut()`. Here is my code:

```r
> table(cut(vector, breaks = 10))

(0.959,10.9]  (10.9,20.8]  (20.8,30.7]  (30.7,40.5]  (40.5,50.4]  (50.4,60.3]  (60.3,70.1]    (70.1,80]    (80,89.9]  (89.9,99.8] 
         175          171          117          103           82           67           54           46           39           31
```

Unfortunately, the intervals are different than the bins we calculated from the possible range (1:100). So I tried fixing this by adding in that range into the vector:

```r
> table(cut(c(1,100,vector), breaks = 10))

(0.901,10.9]  (10.9,20.8]  (20.8,30.7]  (30.7,40.6]  (40.6,50.5]  (50.5,60.4]  (60.4,70.3]  (70.3,80.2]  (80.2,90.1]   (90.1,100] 
         176          171          117          104           82           66           54           48           38           31
```

This almost worked perfectly except the left-most interval which starts from 0.901 for some reason.

---

My questions:

1.) Is there a way to do this (using cut or another function/package) without having to insert artificial data points to get the specified bin ranges?

2.) If not, why does the lower bin start from 0.901 and not 1?

Comment: You could specify the `breaks` as a vector of custom values.  The reason why it does that is based on the code `breaks <- seq.int(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] + dx/1000,` when the length of the breaks is 1

Comment: Try `cut(vector, breaks = 0:10 * 10)`

Comment: Hi Allen, I am interested in dividing up the range 1:100, not 0:100, into 10 bins. Otherwise, yes that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to @Allan Cameron, I understand taht you want to divide your `vector` in 10 bins of the same size. But when you define this number of breaks in the `cut()` function, the size of the intervals calculated by the function, are different accros the groups. As @akrun sad, this occurs because of the method of calculus that the function uses on this case you define only the number's of breaks.

I do not know if there is a way to avoid this in the function. But I think it will be easier if you define the bins as you want as @Gregor Thomas suggested. Here is an example of how I would approach your desire:

```
vec <- sample(1:100, size = 500, replace = T)

# Here I suppose that you want to divide the data in
# intervals of the same length
breaks <- seq(min(vec), max(vec), by = 9.9)

cut(vec, breaks = breaks)
```

Other option, would be the `cut_interval()` function from `ggplot2` package, that cut's the vector in n groups with the same length.

```
library(ggplot2)

cut_interval(vec, n = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does the lower bin start from 0.901 and not 1?

The answer is the first bit of the *Details* section of the `?cut` help page:

> When `breaks` is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length, and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals.

That .1% adjustment is the reason your lower bound is 0.901 --- the upper bound isn't adjusted because it is a closed, `]`, not open `)` interval on that end.

If you'd like to use other breaks, you can specify exact breaks however you want. Perhaps this:

```
my_breaks = seq(1, 100, length.out = 11) ## for n bins, you need n+1 breaks
my_breaks
# [1]   1.0  10.9  20.8  30.7  40.6  50.5  60.4  70.3  80.2  90.1 100.0

cut(vector, breaks = my_breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

But I actually think Allan's suggestion of `0:10 * 10` might be what you really want. I wouldn't dismiss it too quickly:

```
table(cut(1:100, breaks = 0:10*10))

#   (0,10]  (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90] (90,100] 
#       10       10       10       10       10       10       10       10       10       10
```